# Query NHibernate Properties with LINQ

Tags: linq, nhibernate, many-to-many

I have the following (very simplified) domain:

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The **many-to-many** collection is mapped using the following XML:

```
<bag name="Categories" table="ProductsCategories">
  <key column="ProductID" />
  <many-to-many column="CategoryID" class="Category" />
</bag>
```

When I'm loading my categories using the product property all is working correctly:

```
Product product = ProductRepository.Find(1);
var categories = product.Categories;
```

The problem is that when I try to **filter** my collection, for example:

```
Product product = ProductRepository.Find(1);
var categories = product.Categories.Where(c => c.SomeProperty == someValue);
```

The query is **not** executed against the database but it uses LINQ to Objects to filter the result! Is it possible to solve this problem without using HQL and without the need to map a new entity called for example "OrderDetail"?

Comment: This is not a valid answer but does it work if you do : var categories = product.Categories.ToList().Where(c => c.SomeProperty == someValue);

Comment: Yes, but NHibernate will load the entire collection from the database and then it will execute the filter using LINQ to Objects.

Comment: What does your repository.Find(#) method look like?

Comment: It simply calls the `Session.Get` method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the `category`, not the `product`'s categories. (You can do what you originally wanted with `ISession.Filter`, but that didn't take LINQ last time I looked).

e.g.

```
from category in session.Linq<Category>
where category.Products.Contains(product) and category.SomeProperty == someValue
select category
```

Comment: Hi David, unfortunately my relation is a many-to-many and not a one-to-many. My `Category` object doesn't have a `Product` property.

Comment: @StockBreak - I changed the query to use `Contains` for the `Category.Products` property. If Category doesn't have a `Products` property, then add a lazy loaded one.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work since `category.Products` will be evaluated first and then `Contains(product)` will be executed with LINQ to Objects.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Categories` is declared as

```
IList<Category> Categories
```

That means your query will use `Enumerable.Where` instead of `Queryable.Where`.

I'd expect NHibernate to support another interface implementing `IQuerable<T>`, which you'd use to declare your property, e.g.

```
public virtual IQueryableList<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

I haven't used NHibernate in anger, so I don't know what the type actually is, but that's what you should be looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The problem is that I would not like to expose my properties as IQueryable. Should I really do that?

Comment: @StockBreak: If you *don't* expose `IQueryable<T>`, how do you expect the query to be translated into SQL?

Comment: I would like to avoid to publicy expose an IQueryable property since I always hide LINQ operations in repository methods and then simply return IList or IEnumerable properties.  I have just tried this and I get an error while loading orders: _Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag`1[MyDomain.Entities.OrderDetail]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyDomain.Entities.OrderDetail]'_.

Comment: @StockBreak: So where is your query occurring? If it's within your repository method, maybe you can just use an *internal* `IQueryable` property and expose a *public* property which converts that to a list. I don't know enough about NHibernate to know where your error comes from - are you casting to `IQueryable<T>` yourself? (You shouldn't be.)

Comment: Unfortunately the repository cannot access a protected/private property because it is an interface like `IRepository<Order>`.  The exception above raised when I changed the type of my property from `IList` to `IQueryable`.

Comment: @StockBreak: I wasn't expecting you to *just* change it to `IQueryable<T>`. I'd expected NHibernate to have a particular type for this (as EF and LINQ to SQL do).

Comment: Reading [this](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2009/01/should-my-repository-expose-iqueryable.html) article it seems that NHibernate should accept an IQueryable property.  The "exploding" code is something like `var orders = SomeUser.Orders.Where(o => o.SomeProperty == o.someValue)`. Please notice that the `Orders` property is another IList, should I convert this one too?

Comment: @StockBreak: Sounds like it - if you do *any* queries against a non-`IQueryable<T>`, it's going to do them in-process.

Comment: So will I have to change all my collections to IQueryable in order to go this way? Thanks.

Comment: @StockBreak: If you want to be able to query against them in this sort of way, then probably. It's quite possible that you don't really want this in your domain representation, mind you.

Comment: I think that I will go with plain HQL for now. The query is actually very simple: `select c from Products p inner join p.Categories as c where c.someProperty = :someValue`. On the other hand I loose compile-time checking. Thanks anyway!